# Extract files from ploop disk image

Tags: openvz, ploop

I have ploop disk image created by dumping an OpenVZ container. There are two files:

```
791     DiskDescriptor.xml
2.4G    root.hdd
```

Is there any way to extract the whole root file system from there on a non-OpenVZ machine?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to spin up the container, you can simply mount the filesystem image according the manual https://openvz.org/Man/ploop.8

> **`ploop mount`**
>   [-r] [-F] [-d device] [-m mount_point] [-o mount_options] [-t fstype] [-u uuid] DiskDescriptor.xml

Comment: Thanks, but it appears that `ploop` works on OpenVZ hosts only. On Ubuntu 15.10 I am getting `Error in ploop_getdevice (ploop.c:874): Can't open /proc/vz/ploop_minor`. I've edited the question so that it is clear no OpenVZ available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ploop_userspace](https://github.com/FastVPSEestiOu/ploop_userspace/).

```
./ploop_userspace root.hdd &
mount -r -o noload /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt
```

Comment: I got this message  `Unexpected ploop version`

Comment: Open an issue here: https://github.com/FastVPSEestiOu/ploop_userspace/issues